# Control line spacing of section headings

Tags: spacing, sectioning, line-spacing, sections-paragraphs

I use macro and `titlesec` package to create custom `\section` heading.

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1em}{0.3em}

\def \mysection#1{
\section*{\large{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\mysection{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit doloribus odio aliquid aut.}

\lipsum[2]

\mysection{Another section heading with very long text within it that wraps to second line}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: custom section heading]

I want to be able to decrease or increase line spacing between lines of that `\section` heading.

I have tried to do so, by changing `\mysection` macro to:

```
\def \mysection#1{
\section*{\baselineskip=2pt \large{#1}}
}
```

but it doesn't have any effect. (Note that I set `\baselineskip` to `2pt` only to spot it for sure when change happens, not because it is my target line spacing).

I have also tried to change it to:

```
\def \mysection#1{
\section*{\linespread{0.1} \large{#1}}
}
```

which seems to have slight effect on line spacing, but produces nasty indent out of nowhere:

[image: custom section heading with indent]

I have also tried using `setspace` package with its command `\singlespacing`:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1em}{0.3em}

\def \mysection#1{
\section*{\singlespacing \large{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\mysection{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit doloribus odio aliquid aut.}

\lipsum[2]

\mysection{Another section heading with very long text within it that wraps to second line}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

which decreases line spacing, but adds unexpected white space above `\section` headings:

[image]

**Is there any reliable way to modify line spacing of `\section` headings?** I thought that `titlesec` should be able to do it, but I haven't found a clue how to do it in [its documentation](ftp://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf).

Comment: note that `\baselineskip=2pt` indicates the *total* distance between baselines, so with any type of readable size, it's quite impossible.  `\baselineskip=2cm` should have an effect, but if the expansion of `\section` doesn't end with `\par` (i didn't check), then it wouldn't have any effect anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\titleformat` in the `titlesec` package to control the format of the section headings:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\setstretch{0.1}}
\begin{document}
Document Content
\end{document}
```

From the manual, the syntax for the `\titleformat` command is:

```
\titleformat{⟨command⟩}[⟨shape⟩]{⟨format⟩}{⟨label⟩}{⟨sep⟩}{⟨before-code⟩}[⟨after-code⟩]
```

specifying, in order, the title command to modify, the optional "shape" of the title (display/block/...), the format of title, the horizontal length between label and title, and code to execute before and after the title body.

The example above emulates the standard section title.

Comment: What length/measure is set to ``{1em}``?

Comment: @Rafal It's the separation between the label and the title. Have added more details above.

Comment: Thanks for details. I tried to modify it earlier to check effect, but since I was using ``\section*{}`` I didn't see any change as there was no label :)

Answer (score 6):

You *could* do like this:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3ex plus 2ex}{1ex}
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit doloribus odio aliquid aut.}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Another section geading with very long text within it that wraps to second line}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

With a 10pt main font size, `\large` chooses 12pt size.

However, this will give uneven spacing in case characters clash with each other: one with a descender in the first line, one with an ascender in the second line. The example shows it.

I've added also some refinements; the space above a section title should have some flexibility, for instance.

[image]

If you want to be independent of the main font size selected as a class option, change the `\titleformat*` line above into

```
\makeatletter
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\fontsize{\f@size}{\f@size}\bfseries}
\makeatother
```

With `\large` we select the size specified by the class option; this stores the size in `\f@size` and we use it for both arguments.

---

The final version, with barbara beeton's recommended `\raggedright`:

```
\makeatletter
\titleformat*{\section}{\raggedright\large\fontsize{\f@size}{\f@size}\bfseries}
\makeatother
```

Complete example

```
\documentclass[final,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3ex plus 2ex}{1ex}
\makeatletter
\titleformat*{\section}{\raggedright\large\fontsize{\f@size}{\f@size}\bfseries}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit doloribus odio aliquid aut.}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Another section geading with very long text within it that wraps to second line}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From my testing it seems that arguments of ``\fontsize`` command (``{12}{12}``) are responsible for font size and line spacing respectively. Am I right?

Comment: @Rafal Yes, you're right.

Comment: gee, this would really look nicer -- and be more readable -- without the overly wide inter-word spacing.  (most obvious in the "lorem ipsum" example, and it can get lots worse.)  ragged right, please.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your wish is my command. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

```
\def \mysection#1{%  <-----
  \section*{\linespread{0.1}\large#1}% <-----
}
```

Otherwise you'll get a trailing space in front of the title

Comment: It is important to note that space between ``\linespread`` and ``\large`` commands also needs to be removed. It is that way in your example, but just wanted to note that in case it isn't obvious for someone else that this space can create trailing space in document as well.