# Need doublespacing in chapter titles of a thesis (in myreport.cls)

Tags: chapters, line-spacing

I am writing my doctoral thesis using the myreport.cls. The formatting requires double-spaced chapter titles. How can I achieve that? Here is the chapter definition used:

```
% this one creates the chapter heading and makes the chapter title to have number
% it is called by \chapter{...}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        {\centering \normalsize \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp} \space \thechapter   % this uppercase command makes the word ``chapter'' be uppercase at the beginning of each chapter
        \par \nobreak
        \vskip 14\p@    % space between 'CHAPTER x' and the actual title
        }
    \fi
    {\centering
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize \MakeUppercase{#1} \par \nobreak
    \vskip 8\p@     % space between CHAPTER TITLE and the material that starts immediately
    }
  }}
```

With the above definition, the chapter title looks like:

[image]

But I want it to look like:

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try the solution offered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182878/245702 using the `titlesec` package and the `setstretch` command.

Comment: Welcome! Without a complete example, it's hard to know what effect things might have. I'd be inclined to maybe configure a specific font for chapter titles which you then define the line spacing into. (All fonts for text at a given size also specify the spread of the lines.) Whether this is a good approach and how to implement it depends on code you've not shared and the engine you're using (also format, but I assume LaTeX). `myreport.cls` is not standard and we have no idea what's in it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using book class as example here. I believe it should be working in any class setup. Adding `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}` to the chapter head definition in order to have double space for chapter title.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        {\centering \normalsize \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp} \space \thechapter   % this uppercase command makes the word ``chapter'' be uppercase at the beginning of each chapter
        \par \nobreak
        \vskip 14\p@    % space between 'CHAPTER x' and the actual title
        }
    \fi
    {\centering\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize \MakeUppercase{#1} \par \nobreak
    \vskip 8\p@     % space between CHAPTER TITLE and the material that starts immediately
    }
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yz abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yz abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yz}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]